# Adding an image where user touchs ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, touch

Was hoping someone could help me out, Is i possible to place and image where a users touches the screen on an ipad? I'm trying to create a little game(HTML5 javascript) which as 5 or so objects(images). when the user touches the screen in a certain area the the first images shows where the touched? and so on moving through all the images. make sense?

Can this be done with just HTML/javascript? pref jquery.
would I have to use a canvas? I'm thinking I should just be able to out all the images in an array or something then when the users clicks "touches" get those coordinates and position the image there etc.

help really appreciated thanks

Comment: Yeah I know, but for the questions I've asked I've either got no answers or the answer isn't correct. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object from the touch event should have the mouse position data.

```
$('#ident').bind('tap', function(e) {
    $('<img/>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top:  e.pageX,
        left: e.pageY
    });
});
```

Assuming you're using jQuery.mobile of course.

Comment: Thanks for the very speedy reply, can you give me a little help on how I'd use this? thanks